# In Yajara table addColumn in if Condition . can i make it?

Tags: laravel, if-statement, laravel-10

## In this my case in yajara table return row column. i add one extra column if condition true . can i make it?

Here my code

```
`return DataTables::of($data)
    if(Here my condition statment){
        ->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
            return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->name . '</span>';
        })
    }
                ->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
                    return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->show_date . '</span>';
                })
                ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
                    $viewUrl = route('', ['date' => $row->show_date]);
                    $buttons = '';

                    return $buttons;
                })
                if(){
                   ->rawColumns(['show_date', 'action'])
                }else{
                    ->rawColumns(['name','show_date', 'action'])
                }`your text`
                
                ->make(true);`
```

In above can , in yajara table return statement if condition can not work on addcolumn , What alternative way to implement my code.
Please support me , Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable

```
$result = DataTables::of($data);
if(Here my condition statment){
    $result = $result->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
        return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->name . '</span>';
    })
}
$result = $result
    ->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
        return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->show_date . '</span>';
    })
    ->addColumn('action', function ($row) {
        $viewUrl = route('', ['date' => $row->show_date]);
        $buttons = '';

        return $buttons;
    });
if(){
    $result = $result->rawColumns(['show_date', 'action'])
}else{
    $result = $result->rawColumns(['name','show_date', 'action'])
}

return $result->make(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can structure you Datatable like this and add conditional columns.

```
$dt = DataTables::of($data);
if(x == 1){
  $dt = $dt->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
            return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->name . '</span>';
        });
}
$dt = $dt->addColumn('show_date', function ($row) {
                    return '<span class="w-full">' . $row->show_date . 
                  '</span>';
                })
return $dt->make(true);
```